# TextPad Regex: How to Find and Replace character within angle brackets?

Tags: regex, textpad

I've got the below sample text

```
Hello | World
<Hi | Hello|How | are | you><test|string |for |regex>
sample | text <however|replace|pipe>
```

to be converted as below

```
Hello | World
<Hi ~ Hello~How ~ are ~ you><test~string ~for ~regex>
sample | text <however~replace~pipe>
```

i.e. Replace `|` within `<>` with `~`

I tried this `<(?:.*?)(\|)(?:.*?)>` (http://regex101.com/r/mX1sO0)

But it matches only the first `|` withing the angle `<>`. And I am not sure how to replace it. Any directions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your angle brackets are never nested and always correctly balanced, then you can do it:

```
\|(?=[^<>]*>)
```

matches only those pipe characters where the next angle bracket is a closing angle bracket. Then just replace the matches with `~`.

See it [live on regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/lM5kI5).